# img src to php file not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a captcha script to work, so this is my form where I want it:

```
<form action="index.php?s=validate" method="post">
Enter Image Text
<input name="captcha" type="text">
<img src="captcha.php" /><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The captcha.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$code=rand(1000,9999);
$_SESSION["code"]=$code;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 24);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 22, 86, 165);
$fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
imagestring($im, 5, 5, 5,  $code, $fg);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I'm quite sure the problem is     `<img src="captcha.php" /><br>`, but I am not able to figure it out. What's wrong? All i get from all these is this: [image not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YHSk.png).

Comment: where the capctha.php is located/

Comment: in the same directory as the page where i'm using the form

Comment: Try visiting the file directly. Maybe you'll see an error message. Check your server logs.

Comment: @alex_01573 :Tested your code and No problems in your code. Check the file locations.

Comment: @Andrea It says that the image couldn't be displayed because it contains errors.@Subin  Thomas i even tryed /public_html/pages/captcha.php and it's the same thing...

Comment: that means it's not outputting a valid image, probably because it's outputting an error message. Try commenting out the Content-Type line and seeing what it looks like. When you've fixed the error, put the line back.

Comment: @Andrea I did what you said, commented that line and it's the same. Not working/displaying anything. It's so annoying. Is this impossible to solve?

Comment: @Andrea I managed to get it to work. The problem apparently was the directory where captcha.php was located. I moved it to another folder and it was okay. Thank you :D